# web folder will not default to index.html

Tags: html, url, indexing, default

I have a folder on a hosted web server that has an index.html file within it, when I type the URL into the browser along with the index.html the page appears fine like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/subfolder/index.html

however when I type the URL below the page displays but not properly:

http://www.mywebsite.com/subfolder

If I type the second URL without the index.html should the browser not default to the index page?

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: What happens when you add a `/` to the end of your second URL? I smell crappy URL rewriting rules.

Comment: Yea I have added the / to the URL. It is showing the index page but not the correct version, it appears without the header image and seems to remove some of the padding and margins but not all of it. I am using the same browser to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be taking `index.html` by default.
As `.htaccess` file is defined `index.html` as the default file.
I checked both the links and both have given the same output.
Can you please check again?

Comment: Those links were examples, not the OP's actual website ;)